# Best practise to get in sync core code in different projects using git

Tags: git, repository

There is a core part in most of the projects I am working on.

Each project is being stored on a separate git repo.
I want to make a core repository to make all the core changes there and push them to other projects.

I see these ways so far:

- Make one git repo, master for core and branches per project?
- Make one repo for core and somehow push these changes to the others? Parts of the core could be overridden or even deleted.

Please share your thoughts on that subject.

Comment: How are you currently handling your development with the code base spread across multiple repositories?

Comment: By manually merging files from one into others. Just to note, I am not the originator of this flow and current state of it makes me sad.

Comment: I agree, this makes me sad as well.  I think your life will be much easier with everything on one repo.  You can have separate branches if the project needs to move in different directions at the same time.

Comment: I've proposed a way to create core branch in each repo then pull the changes into it using git-annex. Then we can merge it to dev branch. But I don't think that's the best idea.

Comment: Yes, but. 1) I don't think that Jira will work with that architecture 2) thousands of branches into one Source Tree app will definitely look strange

Comment: Thousands of branches?  Really?  Do you need to have so many active branches?  Maybe you can update your question with how you ended up like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101642/discussion-between-zobber-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: From your question, it seems like you have some files that are exactly the same amongst the projects and some files that are project-specific. Am I reading this correctly? If so, the common files should be in a separate git repository and this git repository should be included in your projects as a `git submodule`.